# Limit the numbers of shown characters with php

Tags: php

I need some help to limit the numbers of characters that shows up to 155 in the following code.
How can I do that.

```
case 'page_description':
if($sSeoDesc)
$sRet = '<meta name="description" content="' . $sSeoDesc . '" />';
else
if(!empty($GLOBALS[$this->_sPrefix . 'PageDescription']) && is_string($GLOBALS[$this->_sPrefix . 'PageDescription']) && )
$sRet = '<meta name="description" content="' . bx_html_attribute($GLOBALS[$this->_sPrefix . 'PageDescription']) . '" />';
break;
```

Thanks
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Use php string function substr to return 155 characters of string.

Use like `substr($str, 0 , 155);`

Reference
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Please link the php manual for reference and **not** w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function too!

```
public function limit_text($text) {

        $str2 = explode(' ', $new);
        //print_r($str2);
        $result = null;

        for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($str2) ; $i++) { 

            if($i == 50) //words to break on!
            {
                break;
            }   
            $result .= $str2[$i] . " ";

        }
    return $result;

}
```